# write json to file using camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to write a code which gets a json from API and writing it to an exists file using camel, java spring boot.
This is my code:

```
package camel;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class WriteToFile extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:writeToFile")
        .convertBodyTo(String.class) 
        .to("file:/workers.json")
        .to("log:Data written to file: ${body}");
        
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
  @PostMapping("/writeToFile")
        public String writeToFile(@RequestBody WorkerRequest worker) {
//          producerTemplate.start();
//          producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:myRoute", worker);
            producerTemplate.requestBody("direct:writeToFile", worker);
//          camelConfig.writeToFile();
            return "Employee added to the file successfully.";
        }
```

I see that it is not writing anything to the file, but I do see the json in the log.
what is the promlem?